# Launching Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to write an android app that would comprise of 3 buttons i.e. launch google map, launch market and send email. my code is as follows:

```
public class Intents extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_intents);
}
public void process(View button){  
    Intent intent=null,chooser=null;
if(button.getId()==R.id.LaunchMap){

    intent=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:" + latitude + "," + longitude));
    chooser=Intent.createChooser(intent, "Launch Google Maps");     
    startActivity(chooser);

}else if(button.getId()==R.id.LaunchMarket){
    intent=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("market:https://details?id=dolphin.developers.com"));
    chooser=Intent.createChooser(intent, "Launch Market");      
    startActivity(chooser);
}else if(button.getId()==R.id.SendEmail){

}

}
}
```

however when i run the above code in eclipse i get "no apps can perform this action". what should i change in the code or is there any plugin that i am supposed to add

Comment: At what point are you getting this error? While compiling, when starting your app in emulator, when clicking on a button or something else?

Comment: when i press the buttons on the emulator

Comment: Make sure you are using emulator image with google maps included.

Comment: how do i include the maps to my emulator. i think i am doing it the wrong way

Answer (score 0):

To user Google API-s in emulator you have to use emulator image which contains Google API-s.

For Android 4.4.2 (API 19) there are currently 4 images available:

- ARM EABI v7a System Image
- Intel x86 Atom System Image
- Google APIs (x86 System Image)
- Google APIs (ARM System Image)

Only the last two support Google APIs (including Google Maps), the first two are AOSP images.

To use Google APIs you first have to install image with Google API (for speed, use x86 image with HAX whenever possible). And then select this image as "Target" when creating virtual device with AVD manager.